# Auto updating blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I am a blackberry software developer and my question is about blackberry. I want my own blackberry application to perform version checks with a server, and when the application's version is updated on the server I want this application to download the new version automatically from the server.

Is it possible? Can it be developed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check application version on application startup if new update found exit application and open browser that directs to download link..

```
        if(checkVersion()){
            Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://download.com/file...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

checkVersion() {
    // get version information from server
    // compare with working copy
    if (update)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```